# Improvement in SQL Query - Complex Join / IN / Exists

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, vba

Looking for suggestions on speeding up this query. Access 2007.
The inner query takes a few minutes , full query takes very long (40 - 80 minutes). Result is as expected. Everything is Indexed.

```
SELECT qtdetails.F5, qtdetails.F16, ExpectedResult.DLID, ExpectedResult.NumRows
FROM qtdetails 
INNER JOIN (INVDL 
            INNER JOIN ExpectedResult 
                    ON INVDL.DLID = ExpectedResult.DLID) 
        ON (qtdetails.F1 = INVDL.RegionCode) 
           AND (qtdetails.RoundTotal = ExpectedResult.RoundTotal)
WHERE 
      (qtdetails.F5 IN (SELECT qtdetails.F5 
                            FROM (ExpectedResult 
                                  INNER JOIN INVDL 
                                          ON ExpectedResult.DLID = INVDL.DLID)
                            INNER JOIN qtdetails 
                                    ON (INVDL.RegionCode = qtdetails.F1) 
                                       AND (ExpectedResult.RoundTotal = qtdetails.RoundTotal)

                            GROUP BY qtdetails.F5 
                            HAVING (((COUNT(ExpectedResult.DLID)) < 2));
                            )
          );
```

INVDL - 80,000 records

ExpectedResult - Ten Million records

qtDetails - 12,000 records

The Inner Query will result in around 5000 - 8000 records.
Tried saving the results of the Inner Query in a table. and then using 
Select F5 from qTempTable instead. But still taking a lot of time.

Any help would be very highly appreciated.

Data Type :

```
qtdetails.F5 = Number
qtdetails.F16 = Text
ExpectedResult.NumRows = Number
INVDL.DLID = Number
ExpectedResult.DLID = Number
INVDL.RegionCode = Text
qtdetails.F1 = Text
```

Comment: To get any actual help of this nature, recommendation is to also provide the `EXPLAIN` plan (which is basically how all RDBMSs decide how to look stuff up).  At minimum, knowing what indices you have is required.  How long is 'very long'?  And if your _expected result_ is 10mil rows, it's **going** to take a while.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I have indexed all the columns involved in the joins. Was wondering if converting the "IN" to join would help. Yes "ExpectedResult" will be large , its expected. Using Access - EXPLAIN can be used here ?

Comment: Could you maybe provide some more information here? What are the datatypes of the columns in each of your 3 tables? How do they map to each other (1 to 1, 1 to many etc)? A small subset of sample data would be useful as well, to see how everything fits together.

Comment: @John , made the edits - looking forwad to your answer.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server as a back-end with linked tables? Because Access can generate some bad SQL in these scenarios, translating JET- to Transact-SQL. If you are, you might want to use an ODBC pass-through query for better control over the query. If you aren't ... wtf are you doing with 80k records in a JET or ACE database??.

Comment: @ta.speot.is . This will sound very noob. I am using an Access .mdb file. It meets my purpose with all the tasks I am doing. This is the only bottle neck I have now. Anyhow , Please advise what should be done. Any improvements with vba code , sql code improvments , dividng the code in parts , re organizing the tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild indexes on all the tables involved in the query. Run the query again and check time. It will decrease the execution time. I will update you soon with tuned query if I can.

Keep Querying!

Comment: can you provide a simple code to rebuild indexes on existing tables from VBA.

Comment: Syntax to rebuild index - "ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD;". You can select indexes like this - select index_name from user_indexes where table_name in ('table1','table2');